# CASPERJS Crypto

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, phantomjs, casperjs

I have a problem with my casperjs script. I'm trying to insert data in SQL, but I have two error messages:

> Error: Cannot find module crypto

I tried an `npm install crypto` but that doesn't change anything.
I tried to retrieve the json of nodesjs to pass it in casper, it doesn't work.

The second error message is:

> TypeError: Object is not a constructor (evaluating' new Connection
>   ({config: new ConnectionConfig (config)})")".

My script:

```js
var fs = require('fs');

var casper = require('casper').create({
    verbose: true,
    logLevel: 'error',
    pageSettings: {

        loadImages: true,
        loadPlugins: true,
        clientScripts: ["../libs/jquery.min.js"]
    },
    onDie: function () {
        console.log('Page is died');
    },
    onPageInitialized: function () {
        console.log("Page Initialized");
    }
});


casper.on('remote.message', function (msg) {
    this.echo('remote message caught: ' + msg);
});

casper.on("page.error", function (msg, trace) {
    this.echo("Page Error: " + msg, "ERROR");
});

var url_connexion = 'https://accounts.zoho.eu/signin?servicename=ZohoCRM&signupurl=https://www.zoho.eu/crm/lp/signup.html';


var credentials = {email: "*******@gmail.com", password: "******"};


var identifiant = {input_email: 'input[name="lid"]', input_password: 'input[name="pwd"]', valider_connexion: '#signin_submit'};


var result = [];



var x = require('casper').selectXPath;

casper.start(url_connexion, function() {
        console.log('start1');
        console.log("*************************");
        console.log(" Page de connexion chargee");
        console.log("*************************");
        casper.wait(5000, function(){
        casper.capture("./screenshots/step_1.png");
        console.log('premier_screen')});
    
        this.sendKeys(identifiant.input_email, credentials.email);
        this.sendKeys(identifiant.input_password, credentials.password);
        casper.wait(5000, function(){
        casper.capture("./screenshots/step_2.png");
        console.log('second_screen')});
    
        casper.thenClick(identifiant.valider_connexion, function(){


        casper.wait(5000, function(){

        casper.capture("./screenshots/step_3.png");
        console.log('troisieme_screen');

    });
  });
});
casper.then(function(){
console.log('ATTENTIONNNNNNNE');
var myparameters = {Url:"https://crm.zoho.com/crm/ShowTab.do?module=Invoices"};

casper.wait(5000, function(){
 casper.thenOpen('https://crm.zoho.com/crm/ShowTab.do?module=Invoices', function(){ 
      console.log("step_cap");
casper.capture("./screenshots/step_4.png");
 });             
 });
});

casper.then(function(){
console.log('NEWWWW');
var myparameters = {Url:"https://crm.zoho.com/crm/EntityInfo.do?module=Invoices&id=2957002000000136328"};

casper.wait(5000, function(){
 casper.thenOpen('https://crm.zoho.com/crm/EntityInfo.do?module=Invoices&id=2957002000000136328', function(){ 
      console.log("step_cap");
casper.capture("./screenshots/step_5.png");
casper.then(Extract_data_on_page);
 });             
 });
});



function Extract_data_on_page(){
  console.log('extract_data');
  var zoho_result_identifiant = 
  {
    result_id:'//*[@id="subvalue_INVOICENUMBER"]'
    
  };


    var result_intermediaire = {name :""};
       result_intermediaire.name = this.fetchText('tr#detailViewButtonLayerDummyTableRow #subvalue_INVOICESUBJECT');

result= [];
result.push(result_intermediaire);



casper.then(function(){
console.log('***********************');
console.log(result[0].name);
console.log(result[0]);
console.log(result);
console.log(result_intermediaire);

console.log('***********************');

});
}
casper.then(function(){
var mysql = require('mysql');


    console.log("start_bdd");
    var con = mysql.createConnection({
        user: 'root',
        password: '*****',
        host: 'localhost',
        database: 'zoho_first'
    });
    
    




  con.connect(function(err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log("Connected!");
  var sql = "INSERT INTO Factures (Titre) VALUES ('Company Inc')";
  con.query(sql, function (err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("1 record inserted");
  });
});
});
casper.run();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CasperJS and PhantomJS are not compatible with node.js (although *some* npm packages *may* work if they don't depened on node's internal modules and don't use ES6).

Therefore you won't be able to save data *straight* into MySQL from CasperJS. Luckily there are alternatives:

- You can build a sort of middleman script in the language you know which can receive data from CasperJS and put it into MySQL. You can send data to it via HTTP or CLI. For example it can be a simple PHP script on localhost waiting for POST request.
- You can save data in SQL format using PhantomJS `fs` module and then spawn a MySQL process to import it via [child process](http://phantomjs.org/api/child_process/) module